# Django, using oracledb error msg that I need Oracle 19

Tags: django, django-models, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

I am confused since the documentation for oracledb clearly states that everything past 12.1 should work fine. Could someone please explain to me where I went wrong? The error was created when I tried to create migrations.
The document I am referencing is: [oracledb docs](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_a.html)

Here is the error:

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Oracle 19 or later is required (found 12.2.0.1.0).
```

And here is my databases string in my settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import oracledb
oracledb.version = "8.3.0"
sys.modules["cx_Oracle"] = oracledb
#the above line was added because of error (django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error 
#loading cx_Oracle module: No module named 'cx_Oracle')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': (
                    '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server123)(PORT=1521))'
                    '(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=server.domain.com)))'
                ),
        'USER': 'user123',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'threaded': True,
            
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a restriction in Django itself. What version of Django are you using?

Comment: 4.1. I don’t think it’s related. Must be oracledb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Django thing. From [docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#oracle-notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#oracle-notes):

> "Django supports Oracle Database Server versions 19c and higher."

Also see the [Django 4.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.0/#dropped-support-for-oracle-12-2-and-18c)

> "Dropped support for Oracle 12.2 and 18c".

Try an older version of Django if you can't upgrade the DB

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn’t see that coming. That means I will not be able to use Django for my project.

Comment: Or you have to use an older version of Django until you are able to upgrade your database...

Answer (score 2):

If it is not possible to upgrade the DB, you can try changing the value of the minimum_database_version.
In mysite/mydbengine/base.py

```
from django.db.backends.oracle import base, features


class DatabaseFeatures(features.DatabaseFeatures):
    minimum_database_version = (12,)

class DatabaseWrapper(base.DatabaseWrapper):
    features_class = DatabaseFeatures
```

In settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mydbengine',
    ...
}
```

Also see the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#subclassing-the-built-in-database-backends

Answer (score 0):

You have to comment the method **check_database_version_supported()**.  Be sure of commenting that line on the Virtual Environment and document it.

This is the relative path within ***venv***:

.\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py

[image]